# How to add my data to a python pandas data frame from a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add data to a python dataframe from multiple dictionary items, then operate on that data within the dataframe.

Here is my code below with the desired outcome:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from numpy.random import randn

mylist = [('Jane', 20), ('Helen', 30), ('Jack', 40)]
mydict_one = {'Jane' : 10, 'Helen' : 15, 'Jack' : 20}
mydict_two = {'Jane' : 30, 'Helen' : 45, 'Jack' : 60}


df = pd.DataFrame([], [items[0] for items in mylist], ['mydict_one', 'mydict_two', 'subtracted_value'])
print(df)
```

The desired outcome after adding the data would be as such:

```
       mydict_one  mydict_two  subtracted_value
Jane     10        30          20
Helen    15        45          30
Jack     20        60          40
```

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert `mylist` to a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), build the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [mydict_one, mydict_two, dict(mylist)],
    index=['mydict_one', 'mydict_two', 'subtracted_value']  # "Column names"
).T  # Transpose
```

`df`:

```
       mydict_one  mydict_two  subtracted_value
Jane           10          30                20
Helen          15          45                30
Jack           20          60                40
```

---

We can also calculate subtracted value instead of using `mylist`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [mydict_one, mydict_two],
    index=['mydict_one', 'mydict_two']  # "Column names"
).T  # Transpose

df['subtracted_value'] = df['mydict_two'] - df['mydict_one']
```

`df`:

```
       mydict_one  mydict_two  subtracted_value
Jane           10          30                20
Helen          15          45                30
Jack           20          60                40
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
mylist = [('Jane', 20), ('Helen', 30), ('Jack', 40)]
mydict_one = {'Jane' : 10, 'Helen' : 15, 'Jack' : 20}
mydict_two = {'Jane' : 30, 'Helen' : 45, 'Jack' : 60}


df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=['name', 'subtracted_value'])
df['mydict_one'] = df.name.map(mydict_one)
df['mydict_two'] = df.name.map(mydict_two)

df
```

[image]